# Magento EDA system how to avoid event loop?

Tags: php, magento, eda

I am trying to hook **catalog_product_save_after** event.
Here is config.xml

```
<events>
   <catalog_product_save_after>
     <observers>
       <observer_name_here>
         <class>My_Class_Model_Observer</class>
         <method>methodToCall</method>
         <type>singleton</type>
       </observer_name_here>
     </observers>
   </catalog_product_save_after>
</events>
```

And below is the code that runs in **methodToCall()**:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
$product->setName('TESTING 123');
$product->save();
```

*Issue Is*: 
When the event **catalog_product_save_after** is fired. The code written in **methodToCall()** fire the **catalog_product_save_after** again. And according Magento EDA system **methodToCall()** called again which fires the **catalog_product_save_after** once again. So the system stuck in series of firing and listening the same event.

My Questions:

1. How to avoid this situation ?
2. Is there any way to disable to Magento event dispatch functionality for temporary purposes (*without re-writing **dispatchEvent** method of **Mage_Core_Model_App*** *if possible*).
3. How to prevent infinite looping, if the observer fires the same event that instantiated the observer. Like in case above.

Comment: Why don't you use catalog_product_save_before event? Can you explain more what are you trying to achive in your method, maybe we can offer an alternative solution rather than trying to disabling event dispatches.

Comment: @muhammedv If I use `catalog_product_save_before` the same thing gonna happen.  The issue is EDA system, What if the observer fires the same event. How to prevent system to get into the looping.

Comment: If you use catalog_product_save_before, you won't call $product->save(); It will be saved after. Just get product with $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct(); in the event observer method and call setName() and don't call save(). It will be saved. Test it.

Comment: That's cool. But i have to use the new values and using those values I have to update another product. That's why I can't use the **catalog_product_save_before** event.

Comment: You can get new values in catalog_product_save_before

Comment: Also you can get old values by calling $product->getOrigData();

Comment: Also you can check if there is a data change in product model by calling $product->hasDataChanges()

Comment: Agree!  What I seeking for solution for this looping situation. Can we built something in Magento that can disable all the dispatching functionality temporary ? I am trying with re-writing the dispatchEvent function.

Comment: If you dont call save() it won't loop

Comment: Yeah that I can see :) But I am not avoiding this situation. I am looking for a solid solution for this.

Comment: ROBIN, calling save function in catalog product save observer is wrong. You need to find another way to achive what you want, not a way to disable event dispatching functionality temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to *use the new values and using those values you have to update another product* you can observe **catalog_product_save_before** event. Your config looks OK, here you are an example **methodToCall** function:

```
public function methodToCall(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $event    = $observer->getEvent();
    $product  = $event->getProduct();

    if($product->hasDataChanges()) { //somethings changed

        $newName = $product->getName();
        $oldName = $product->getOrigData('name');

        //do stuff here
        //don't call $product->save() It WILL be saved. If you call save() you will create a loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe fundamentally, this is probably the wrong approach for your use case, I think you should probably be looking at `save_before`. However, I've seen people use the Mage::registry for this in the past.

```
if(!Mage::Registry("somekey")) {
    Mage::Register("somekey", true);
    //LOGIC
}
```

Now, in this instance, "somekey" should be something specific, and probably specific to this product too so that if you're saving multiple products, it doesn't affect them.